# Bash Script: list all directories EXCEPT specified

Tags: linux, bash, centos, directory, centos7

I have bash script show directory:\

```
for D in /home/*; do
    if [ -d "${D}" ]; then #If a directory
        domain=${D##*/} # Domain name
        echo "- "$domain;
    fi
done
echo "Finished";
```

I have 2 Directory name "default" and "suspended". I do not want to list those 2 directory names.
Please help me!

Comment: `if [ -d "${D}" -a "${D}" != 'default' -a "${D}" != 'suspended' ] ...`

Comment: Don't use `-a`; use `[ ... ] && [ ... ] && [ ... ]` instead. Or since this is `bash`, `[[ ... && ... && ... ]]`.

Comment: You can use `/home/*/` to select only directories in the first place, eliminating the need for the `-d` test.

Comment: @chepner hey what's wrong with `-a`? I like it

Comment: It's non-standard (though recognized as an extension) and considered obsolete by POSIX.

Comment: @oguzismail [Bash FAQ 017](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/017) even says that the results are undefined for `-a`.

Comment: didn't know that. thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

Turn on extended globbing:

```
shopt -s extglob
for D in !(default|suspended)/
do
  domain=...
  ...
done
```

The !(...)/ selects all directories except those in the list.